# f2py with specific data type

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I would like to move my old Fortran code to python but I would like to still use some of my old Fortran subroutines.

I know that there is the f2py module. According to f2py manual the subroutine has to properly written with clear input and output.

My question is: is it possible to use with f2py data type. In the following an example of what I mean for fortran data type:

```
 TYPE tPARAM
    REAL                            :: aa      
    REAL,  DIMENSION(2)             :: LIMIT       
    REAL,  ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: SET          
 END TYPE tPARAM
```

I mean pass to the subroutine data type as in Fortran framework?

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible. With f2py, you need to pass separately the arguments, using only plain Fortran data types. NumPy arrays can be passed around, though, which is already very nice. If you can map your type to a C struct you can use the iso_c_binding feature (look for it on SO for instance). Allocatable members are not allowed as far as I remember, you'd need to pass allocatable content separately anyway. I can only recommend iso_c_binding + cython however for modern Fortran bindings.